# How should we tag The Stanley Parable(s)?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[The Stanley Parable](http://store.steampowered.com/app/221910/) is now a stand-alone game on Steam.  It started off as a [mod](http://www.moddb.com/mods/the-stanley-parable).  It also has an interesting Demo for the full game, but that is a potentially different issue.

The main problem here is that the mod and full game are the same name.  All versions (including the Demo) have questions, but they are all tagged as [the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable).

Comment: Can you remove the last paragraph (and maybe the last sentence of the second paragraph) from the question and move it to an answer for voting and counter-proposals?

Comment: I took the liberty of moving those lines into a CW answer for you so that we can get on with discussing how to tag these.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for that. I was unable to get on for a few days.

Answer (score 22):

This is precisely the same situation we had for SimCity so I suppose we could go a similar route:

- new game: [the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable) ← [the-stanley-parable-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-2013)
- old game: [the-stanley-parable-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-2011)

The fact that the original game was a mod is an implementation detail; it's basically irrelevant for us. A question tagged [the-stanley-parable-mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-mod) sounds like a question about a mod for The Stanley Parable.

Using the year of release date is both unambiguous, clearer and it's consistent with what we've been doing.

Comment: Using the year is also consistent with disambiguation conventions of encyclopaedias and public databases, and it's the long-accepted way to handle identical movie titles.

Comment: +1 though, I agree with @Zommuter below that [tag:the-stanley-parable-demo] should be its own separate tag, rather than [tag:the-stanley-parable] and [tag:demo] tags.  Unlike most demos, it is not just some small part of the Stanley Parable - it is actually ts own, completely separate game.

Comment: +1 - what @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft said

Comment: I think mods on the new game should include the mod tag.  How did we handle other games like this (such as Counter Strike, Day Z, and Alien Swarm)?

Comment: So should questions specifically about the 2013 version only have the 2013 tag, or should they carry both tags so that a user can view all Stanley Parable related questions at once?

Comment: @Zibbobz as with any other game series, just use the game name tag.

Answer (score 10):

As one who has played all 3 versions, I (Batophobia) can verify that each one is different.

I suggest changing the questions about the mod to [the-stanley-parable-mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-mod) and leaving the questions about the full game as [the-stanley-parable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable).  As for the demo, it can probably remain under the full game tag and maybe add the [demo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demo) tag to it.

<sub>*(This self-answer moved from the question to this CW for voting purposes.)*</sub>

Comment: This is essentially what I suggested on chat as well.

Comment: Making the demo waste _two_ tags is nonsense - since the demo is entirely different, it should simply have its own tag [tag:the-stanley-parable-demo]

Comment: [tag:demo] is an awful tag and should absolutely not be used.

Comment: -1 they are both standalone source-engine mods, it's just that one costs money.  You can play both without owning HL2.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Indeed, on second thought the way it's currently used it is quite a meta-tag - no use on its own. Maybe we should ban it entirely?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Since the Source SDKs were created, all kinds of stuff that previous required HL2 no longer does. The line separating "HL2 mod" from "Source Engine game" is almost non-existent now.

Comment: ...yes, that's my point.

Comment: @Zommuter I agree with you, but technically it is the official demo of the game, so I can accept either way.

Answer (score -4):

A counter-proposal derived from edits that have been done on Main:

- [the-stanley-parable-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-2011) for the original mod version
- [the-stanley-parable-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-2013) for the Steam "HD Remix" version

Comment: Absolute nonsense. Retagging like this means we end up having to make [the-stanley-parable] a synonym of either - and which one do we choose then? It also means *both* tags deviate from the actual name of the game.